# Is there a way to make this function generic?

Tags: swift, generics

I have a data set:

```
struct MyData {
  var name: String
  var date: Date
  var quantity: Int
  var inStock: Bool
}
```

That is then used in an array

```
let myArray: [MyData] = [...]
```

And I'm currently writing methods to change values..

```
func changeName(to newName: String) { myArray[0].name = newName }

func changeDate(to newDate: Date) { myArray[0].date = newDate }

func changeQuantity(to newQuantity: Int) { myArray[0].quantity = newQuantity}
```

And I start thinking that this would be a perfect case for generics and say something like

```
func changeValue<Value>(to newValue: Value) { ... }
```

only problem is I can't make the *dot notation* generic

If I could say

```
myArray[0].value = newValue
```

Any guidance on the matter would be helpful!

Comment: I don’t have time to write up an answer, but look up Look “key paths”.

Comment: Why do you need this exactly? What would be the advantage of something like `myArray.change(value: \.name, to: "new name")` over `myArray[0].name = "new name"`?

Comment: well you're missing a key point. 

I'm trying to avoid having to say .name. As Alexander alluded to, there is a way to make the whole function generic where I don't have to say any property. I don't have to use .name or .date I can just make one function that will give me multiple options at the call site

Comment: What if there are two properties with the same type?

Comment: I'm currently researching keyPaths and what to do in that case, but I think I can access by the property name which would allow me to pick a specific value regardless of duplicate types

Comment: @SergioBost I don't see any advantage of writing a method to change the element properties. Btw you need to first declare them as variables instead of constants. If you really want to use key path all you need is `myArray[0][keyPath: \.name] = "whatever"` but IMO it is easier to do as Martin R suggested `myArray[0].name = "whatever"`

Comment: Btw why would you have a method to only change the first element of the collection ?

Comment: @LeoDabus I put this code snippet together purely for show and tell. Of course I wouldn't just want to update the first collection, in the real code I'm passing in an index as a parameter of the function but that's really outside the scope of my question and yes the lets should be vars

Comment: The only way to do what you are trying to accomplish is adding a switch and trying to cast the newValue to String, Date, Int or Bool and assigning the value to the respective property. Something like `func changeValue<T>(to newValue: T) {`
`switch newValue {` `case let name as String:` `myArray[0].name = name` `case let date as Date:` `myArray[0].date = date`
`case let quantity as Int:` `myArray[0].quantity = quantity` `case let inStock as Bool:` `myArray[0].inStock = inStock` `default: fatalError()` `}` `}` but you are going the wrong way. Thats not what generics are meant for.

Comment: @LeoDabus There is a way, check out the new answer

Comment: @SergioBost  that’s obvious. I meant without passing the keypath

Comment: @LeoDabus I wasn't aware of that way of doing it the way Joakim wrote it, but I thought that you were implying that what you wrote was the only of doing it because you prefaced it by saying "the only way to do .." But no worries, thank you , still insightful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `var` declare your properties you can add the following function to your struct

```
mutating func setValue<Value>(_ value: Value, for keyPath: WritableKeyPath<Self, Value>) {
    self[keyPath: keyPath] = value
}
```

And then use it like

```
var myData = MyData(name: "abs", date: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0), quantity: 0, inStock: false)

myData.setValue(500, for: \.quantity )
myData.setValue(Date(), for: \.date)
myData.setValue(true, for: \.inStock)
```

which will update the object

> MyData(name: "abs", date: 2021-03-27 18:26:26 +0000, quantity: 500, inStock: true)

Then how you want to use it for your array is a bit unclear to me but here you at least have a tool to work with.

Comment: Yes! If I could upvote you more than once I would. Thats exactly what I was looking for. Side note: I don't understand why people down vote a question, its one thing to be poorly presented, by why shame the questioner.. anyway Thanks!

Comment: @SergioBost why not simply `myData.quantity = 500` ? I don't understand the purpose of this method other than didactic

Comment: @LeoDabus Well if I only had one property to update then I agree its pointless but the whole purpose of my question was to avoid having to write a function to update each property. With this code above I can do so with one method. And I think your method would work as well but this has a similar effect and less lines of code

Comment: Sorry but you don’t need a method for this. You can simply use the subscript along with the property and generally you may need to update more than one property at a time